# .Net CodeDom - Create delegate with AddressOf operator equivalent?

Tags: .net, vb.net, codedom

**Edit:**

Is there a way to create a delegate instance in .Net using CodeDom? I want to generate something which looks like the following:

```
Dim myDelegate As someDelegateType = New someDelegateType(AddressOf implementingMethod)
```

Below is more info on the context...

### **Original Question:**

I am using CodeDom from the .Net framework (v3.5 if it matters) to generate a class. One of the classes defines a delegate method which in VB.Net looks like:

```
Public Delegate Function filterByIdDelegate(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean
```

I then have a method which will provide the implementation:

```
Private Function filterById(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (obj.ID = id)
End Function
```

Here's the problem; how do you create an instance of the delegate (using the equivalent of AddressOf for VB.Net)? I am currently doing this (`<filterByIdFunctionName>` is a string holding the name of the delegate function, `' is the name of the delegate field):

```
Dim getFunction = New System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod()
With getFunction
'Declare delegate instance
.Statements.Add( _
    New System.CodeDom.CodeVariableDeclarationStatement( _
        New System.CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(<filterByIdDelegateName>) _
        , "myDelegate" _
        , New System.CodeDom.CodeObjectCreateExpression( _
            <filterByIdDelegateName> _
            , New System.CodeDom.CodeExpression() { _
                New System.CodeDom.CodeMethodReferenceExpression( _
                    New System.CodeDom.CodeThisReferenceExpression() _
                    , <filterByIdFunctionName> _
                  ) _
              } _
          ) _
      ) _
  )
End With
```

This produces the following output:

```
Dim myDelegate As filterByIdDelegate = New filterByIdDelegate(Me.filterById)
```

What I'm looking to get is:

```
Dim myDelegate As filterByIdDelegate = New filterByIdDelegate(AddressOf Me.filterById)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after (*much*...) more digging on the internet I found an obscure post on [dotNetMonster](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-vb/55940/CodeDom-and-Addressof) (thanks to **Zach** aka **bluedude** who posted the useful code) which had a related solution for C#. For the benefit of the StackOverflow folks, here's my VB.Net re-hack of his code (customized for my scenario):

```
    Dim createDelegate = New CodeDom.CodeDelegateCreateExpression( _
            New CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(filterByIdDelegate.Name) _
            , New System.CodeDom.CodeThisReferenceExpression() _
            , "filterById" _
        )

    Dim varInit = New CodeDom.CodeObjectCreateExpression( _
            New CodeDom.CodeTypeReference(filterByIdDelegate.Name) _
            , createDelegate _
        )

    Dim varDecl = New CodeDom.CodeVariableDeclarationStatement( _
            filterByIdDelegate.Name _
            , "myDelegate" _
            , varInit _
        )
```

The output is:

```
Dim myDelegate As filterByIdDelegate = _
    New filterByIdDelegate(AddressOf Me.filterById)
```

In order to create a reference to a method you must actually pass in the create delegate expression itself as a parameter. The sample above will both declare a new variable called `myDelegate` of type `filterByIdDelegate.Name` and then assign it a new delegate instance referencing the implementation method of `Me.filterById()` (c# `this.filterById()`).